# Authorize doesn't work in Signalr of ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-signalr, asp.net-core-2.1

I've upgraded my project from ASP.Net Core 2.0 to ASP.NET Core 2.1 by following [this tutorial](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/upgrading-aspnet-core-2-application-aspnet-core-2-1-preview-1).

Everything was fine until I applied Signar Core 2.1 to my project.

This is my `Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, SolidAccountRequirementHandler>();

        services.AddCors(
            options => options.AddPolicy("AllowCors",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                })
        );

        services.AddAuthorization(x =>
        {
            x.AddPolicy("MainPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.Requirements.Add(new SolidAccountRequirement());
            });
        });

        services.AddSignalR();

        #region Mvc builder

        var authenticationBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        authenticationBuilder.AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
            // You also need to update /wwwroot/app/scripts/app.js
            o.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();

            // Initialize token validation parameters.
            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters();
            tokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience = "audience";
            tokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = "issuer";
            tokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SigningKey"));
            tokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = false;

            o.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
        });

        // Construct mvc options.
        services.AddMvc(mvcOptions =>
            {
                ////only allow authenticated users
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddRequirements(new SolidAccountRequirement())
                    .Build();

                mvcOptions.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1); ;

        #endregion
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCors("AllowCors");

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
        });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

This is my `SolidRequirementHandler`

```
public class SolidAccountRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SolidAccountRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SolidAccountRequirement requirement)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

This is my `ChatHub.cs`:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    [Authorize(Policy = "MainPolicy")]
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
}
```

What I expected was `MainPolicy` would be called when I used my AngularJS app to connect to `ChatHub`. However, `OnConnectedAsync()` function was called without checking request identity.

The policy of MVC Controller was applied successfully, but Signalr's doesn't.

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted this question onto Signalr github [issue page](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1764).
Here is the answer they gave me .
I tried and it worked successfully:

The solution is to put `[Authorize]` attribute onto `ChatHub`

```
[Authorize(Policy = "MainPolicy")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
}
```

Just share to who doesn't know :)

Comment: What is the namespace of Authorize attribute?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, there are four key things:

1- In your Startup.cs be aware of this Order inside `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)`

```
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization( );
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<myChat>("/chat");
            });
```

the `app.UseAuthorization( );` should always be between `app.UseRouting();` and  `app.UseEndpoints()`.

2- SignalR doesn't send Tokens in Header but it sends them in  Query. In your startup.cs inside `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` You have to configure your app in a way to read Tokens from the query and put them in the header. You can Configure your JWT in this way:

```
  services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidIssuer = [Issuer Site],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes([YOUR SECRET KEY STRING]))
                };
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var path = context.Request.Path;
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && path.StartsWithSegments("/chat"))
                        {
                            
                            context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", new[] { $"Bearer {accessToken}" });
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

3- Your Client should send Token when it wants to establish a connection. You can add token to  Query when building the connection.

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(
"http://localhost:5000/chat", {
    skipNegotiation: true,
    transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
    accessTokenFactory: () => "My Token Is Here"}).build();
```

4- I didn't add a default Athuentication scheme inside `services.AddAuthentication()`
So every time I have to specify my authorization scheme like this.  `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`
And Finally, You can Protect your Chat Class Like this

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;

        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        public class myChat : Hub
        {
            ///Some functions
        }
```

It seems that Using statements is important, So make sure using the right ones.
[SignalR hub Authorize attribute doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54153876/signalr-hub-authorize-attribute-doesnt-work)

**Note**: I have a problem with Authorizing only a single method in the `myChat` class. I don't know why.