# SignalR hub Authorize attribute doesn't work

Tags: c#, authentication, signalr, azure-active-directory, signalr-hub

I'm using SignalR to send notification to angular. But i want to make it user specific. The user is logged in with azure ad. And i have a [Authorize] on the hub but the authorisation fails. But in my controller it works fine.

What i have tried so far. I tried this services.AddAuthentication from the microsoft site. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-2.2
But then my controller can't verify the token because the token isn't in the url but in the header.

startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions();

        // Add custom configuration/resource files
        services.ConfigureSettings(Configuration);
        services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
            options.Level = System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Fastest
        );

        services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
        {
            options.EnableForHttps = true;
            options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
        });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200"));
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options));           

        services.AddSignalR();

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {        
            options.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelStateFilter());

        }).AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        });
```

my hub:

```
 [Authorize]
 public class NotifyHub : Hub<ITypedHubClient>
   {
    public Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {

        return Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId)
               .BroadcastMessage("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }

    public Task Log(string email)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Context.ConnectionId);

        return Clients.Caller.BroadcastMessage("succes", "string");
    }

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {

        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
}
```

angular SignalR service:

```
private createConnection() {     
   this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()  
  .withUrl('https://localhost:44334/notify', { accessTokenFactory: () => { 
   return this.adalSvc.accessToken }  })      
  .build(); 
}
```

I want to get the user in my hub so i can map the users to the connection id's.

Answer (score 3):

You're not showing your `using` statements and I see you are also using MVC. Maybe you're using the wrong AuthorizeAttribute?

Make sure you are using `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.AuthorizeAttribute` and not the MVC one.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with SignalR is that it cannot modify the header to send the token so

```
       services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
       .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options));
```

does not work with SignalR as the token is expected in the URL.

The following however works with both Authenticated API calls and Authenticated SignalR connections

```
services.AddAuthentication(options = >{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options = >{
   options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
   options.SaveToken = true;
   options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"];
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() {
    // These need to be set correctly after checking that it works
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateLifetime = false,
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
    ValidateActor = false
};
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents {
    OnMessageReceived = ctx = >{
        if (ctx.Request.Query.ContainsKey("access_token")) 
             ctx.Token = ctx.Request.Query["access_token"];
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```

});

You can test this in your hub

```
       public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
       {
         var Oid = (Context.User.FindFirst(c => 
                   c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"))?.Value;
         Debug.WriteLine(Oid);
       }
```

Both [Authorize] attributes for API and SignalR come from

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
```

Answer (score 1):

best method for using authorization for hubs is to force the application add the jwt token from the query string to the context
and its working for me via this method

put this inside your program.cs (dot net 6):

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{



o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
    ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey
        (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidateLifetime = false,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
};

o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
{
    OnMessageReceived = context =>
    {
        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) == false)
        {
            context.Token = accessToken;
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};


});
```

and my hubs are like this  its using the main authorize method of asp

```
 [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Authorize]
    public async Task myhub()
    {

       //do anything in your hub

    }
```

[youtube totorial that helped me to solve this problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFC56aztigI)